# Measuring load per database in Postgres using 'active' processes in pg_stat_activity?

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

I am trying to measure the load that various databases living on the same Postgres server are incurring, to determine how to best split them up across multiple servers. I devised this query:

```
select
 now() as now,
 datname as database,
 usename as user,
 count(*) as processes
from pg_stat_activity
where state = 'active'
 and waiting = 'f'
 and query not like '%from pg_stat_activity%'
group by
 datname,
 usename;
```

But there were surprisingly few active processes!

Digging deeper I ran a simple query that returns 20k rows and took 5 seconds to complete, according to the client I ran it from. When I queried `pg_stat_activity` during that time, the process was *idle*! I repeated this experiment several times.

The Postgres documentation says *active* means

> The backend is executing a query.

and *idle* means

> The backend is waiting for a new client command.

Is it really more nuanced than that? Why was the process running my query was not *active* when I checked in?

If this approach is flawed, what alternatives are there for measuring load at a database granularity than periodically sampling the number of active processes?

Comment: Did you maybe disable auto commit in the session where you queried `pg_stat_activity`? That view does not change during the lifetime of a transaction. So if you disabled auto commit you need to commit after each select to end that transaction

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is interesting. I used pgAdmin III. It was configured to auto-commit. I saw changes to `pg_stat_activity` during the experiment; just not the changes I expected. Good thought though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your expectations regarding `active`, `idle`and `idle in transaction` are very right. The only explanation I can think of is a huge delay in displaying data client side. So the query indeed finished on server and session is `idle` and yet you don't see the result with client.

regarding the load measurement - I would not rely on number of active sessions much. Pure luck to hit the fast query in active state. Eg hypothetically you can check `pg_stat_activity` each second and see one active session, but between measurement one db was queried 10 times and another once - yet none of those numbers will be seen. Because they were active between executions. And this 10+1 active states (although mean that one db is queried 10times more often) do not mean you should consider load at all - because cluster is so much not loaded, that you can't even catch executions. But this unavoidably mean that you can catch many active sessions and it would not mean that server is loaded indeed.

so at least take `now()-query_start` to your query to catch longer queries. Or even better save execution time for some often queries and measure if it degrades over time. Or better select `pid` and check resources eaten by that pid.

Btw for longer queries look into pg_stat_statements - looking how they change over time can give you some expectations on how the load changes

Comment: But assuming the one database was consistently getting hit 10 times more than another, wouldn't repeated sampling eventually give an accurate picture of that, even if some measurements happen to occur at times when the database is under very light load as you describe? Or is your point that "consistency" isn't a good assumption to make when it comes to measuring load in a production environment? I am intrigued by your idea of mapping the databases to pids and using other tools to measure their resource consumption... I can't see the pids though becuase it's an RDS instance.

Comment: oh. with RDS I think you can't make any assumption about the load distributed over databases... and yes - my point is that consistency of load is not measurable by periodic checks. Of course If you have a limited know set of queries, running at known time - you can calculate the load. but if you have MANY unpredictable queries, counting them with periodical select from pg_stat_statement is like counting number of cars, running highway different hours to measure the damage to the road - yes - it will be different different hours, but not only (and not mostly) by count of cars seen in ONE SPOT